# How to post on multiple queues using single job/ JMSwriter in spring batch

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch, jmstemplate

I am a newbie at Spring Batch and have recently started using it.

I have a requirement where I need to post/write the messages read from each DB record on different queues using single Job. As I have to use reader to read the messages from DB and use processor to decide on which queue I have to post it.

So my question is Can I use single JMSwriter to post the messages on different queues as I have to use single Job and DB Reader.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know `JMSwriter` not supports it (it writes to default destination of `jmsTemplate`).

But you may just implement your own `ItemWriter`, inject all `jmsTemplates` in it and write custom decistion logic to select appropriate destionation and write to it.

Another way - use [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html) , put a set of `JmsWriters` to it and select one by your classifier

Comment: Thanks Michail,

I was skimmming through Spring Batch options and thought of the Classifiers :) .... I think that would be apt for my requirement ...