# How to display ActionErrors on page in action which implements ExecuteAndWaitInterCeptor

Tags: struts2, jsp-tags, interceptor

This is my first question on Stackoverflow and I am very hopeful for the answer.

I have a struts 2 action which runs very long so I have implemented the Executeandwaitinterceptor  to show the intermediary JSP while background process is complete.

However as struts 2 docs suggest

> Because the action will be running in a seperate thread, you can't use ActionContext because it is a ThreadLocal. This means if you need to access, for example, session data, you need to implement SessionAware rather than calling ActionContext.getSession().

I have impelemented SessionAware and it works perfectly.

The issue I am facing is while adding actionerrors. I have requirement where on conditional base I have to show some errors to user from that long running process as I believe method addActionError() of [ActionSupport](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html) class uses ActionContext internally and my action not being able to use it as it is running in separate thread and not in ThreadLocal.

When I set debug mode on I got this message

> Action Context not initialized

How to use actionerrors in this case?

Comment: [Don't lie now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483197/how-to-post-on-multiple-queues-using-single-job-jmswriter-in-spring-batch)... If you store a thread safe list of errors in the user session then you can drain them in the polling request.

Comment: Thanks Boris...

But How can I use arguments/parameter on the fly if I dont use addText().

Pardon my ignorance but have used actionerrors very little.

BTW I wasn't lying last time .. I actually did research a bit :)

Comment: oops it's been quite a time for that question and I thought that I asked that particular question in spring forum :)

Comment: Just store an `Object` that contains the `String` and the `List<Object>` that are the arguments in the `Session` - then use the `getText` method in the `wait` result JSP.

Comment: @Boris the Crawler :D

Comment: Thanks Boris .. got your point will... try and implement it.....